# I want to property grid open on Treeview item selection using c#

Tags: c#, treeview, propertygrid

I have been trying to open a property grid on the selection of a tree node and then bind the values of the property grid to the selected tree node in C#. This way if I create a new tree node it has its own values in the property grid.

Can anyone give an example of how that can be done or probably suggest me on the code below,

```
public partial class WPFpropertygriddemo : Window
{
    public WPFpropertygriddemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _propertyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void myTreeView_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        Item itemsub = (Item)tvi.Header;
        if (itemsub != null)
        {
            _propertyGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            // System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(itemsub.DisplayValue);
            _propertyGrid.SelectedObject = itemsub;
        }
    }
}
public class Item : MyModelINotifyProperty
{
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected = false;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    private string _sample;

    public string Sample
    {
        get
        {
            return _sample;
        }
        set
        {
            _sample = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sample");
        }
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : MyModelINotifyProperty
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item() {DisplayValue = "Item1", IsSelected = false, Sample = "Sample: I am Item1"},
            new Item() {DisplayValue = "Item2", IsSelected = true, Sample = "Sample: I am Item2"},
            new Item() {DisplayValue = "Item3", IsSelected = false, Sample = "Sample: I am Item3"}
        };
        }
    }
}



public abstract class MyModelINotifyProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is where is TreeViewItem defined and what is the code line 
"TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
doing? I have an error at the TreeViewItem and Original source. Am I supposed to add a reference to use the e.original?

Thanks
Sree.